# How to noindex on paginated pages in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, paging, meta-tags

This question is almost a copy of: [How to noindex comment/reply in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18299/how-to-noindex-comment-reply-in-drupal-7)

However in this case i would like to know how to add noindex,follow on paginated pages. For example I want to add noindex,follow on domain.com/artiklar?page=7 but not on domain.com/artiklar

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: This is how would you do that, according to [this page](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/) Disallow /artiklar?*

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do specifically with Drupal, but I've answered it anyway.

Comment: There are Drupal methods for handling metadata w/o manually editing robots.txt

Comment: I should have clearifed that it should allow following of links:
noindex,follow

I dont think that is possible with robots.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Metatag module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) and [Metatag Quick module](https://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) to add a "noindex" meta tag to the artiklar content type for pagination pages (you will use the path based metatags part of metatags_quick).

Comment: I have that module but I can not find that setting. Can you tell me where it is?

Comment: I lied, you need metatags_quick as well, with that you can do path based metatags, just add the page=* to the path.

Comment: So add the metatags_quick then go to Path-based meta tags, add the artiklar?page=* as the path, then go back to general and check off "robots" then go back to path based meta tags and click edit, then check off "noindex".

Comment: Many thanks. I accept your answer as the correct one. I guees its possible to do "follow" combined with noindex with this module?

Comment: Yah you should be able to do both.

Comment: Steven, it almost works. I having trouble with getting the wildcard to work though. As soon as I add the star * the robots meta disapear. Any idea why? Not even artik* works.